# Htaccess Problem in PHP

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I rewrite

```
www.example.com/test.php?search=demo
```

to

> www.example.com/test/?search=demo

using htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put that into your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```